# android hello world program taking too much time to run

Tags: android

I had followed android developer forum for installation and done all the steps. But finally when i try to run the application , it is just handing on "ANDROID" black screen with below message on console

```
[2011-10-09 23:59:27 - HelloAndroid] Android Launch!
[2011-10-09 23:59:27 - HelloAndroid] adb is running normally.
[2011-10-09 23:59:27 - HelloAndroid] Performing my.mobile.test.HelloAndroidActivity activity launch
[2011-10-09 23:59:27 - HelloAndroid] Automatic Target Mode: launching new emulator with compatible AVD 'my_avd'
[2011-10-09 23:59:27 - HelloAndroid] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'my_avd'
[2011-10-09 23:59:33 - HelloAndroid] New emulator found: emulator-5554
[2011-10-09 23:59:33 - HelloAndroid] Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore') to be launched...
```

It already took 15-20 min and still hanging there. Am i missing anything. Please suggets

[image]

Answer (score 3):

From the looks of your screen shot you are running an emulator with android 3.0 in a tablet configuration. There are many problems with the android 3.0 emulator in terms of speed and reliability. For testing a program as simple as the one you describe create a new emulator using avd with the target sdk as 2.3 or earlier with maybe a WVGA screen. This should work fine for testing your code.

Comment: you are correct. I'm using 3.2. Now i'm installing 2.3 and let you know the update. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Yup no problem, I too have been very frustrated trying to test using the emulator in tablet mode. My solution was to just buy a tablet to test on :)

Comment: this time new emulator has come (2.3) and it's taking some time. Let's see what happens. Also i had one more doubt, i'm selecting eclipse project and selected run as -> Android Application. Is this right way of running. Because i cannot see run as android when i select particular java file

Comment: Oops..now i'm getting some different kind of error..[2011-10-10 00:56:03 - ddms]Failed to reopen debug port for Selected Client to: 8700

Comment: finally it worked after changing hosts file as 127.0.0.1 localhost and then disabling firewall,windows defender, antivirus , enabling wipe out while running configuration , and then restarting the eclipse again

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue but what I have done is to start the emulator (in avd manager) and after that, I deployed the application and it works fine.

Regards.